# How to extract values from a list of dictionaries and group and convert to a single dictionary with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a sql proc returning results like this

```
GroupId     PersonId
1           2
1           3
2           4
2           6
```

This is my dapper query calling the stored proc

```
List<IDictionary<string, object>> result = (dbconnection.Query("MyStoredProcName", null,
                    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, commandTimeout: 0)
                    as IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>).ToList();
```

I tried this 
`var selectManyResult = result.SelectMany(r => r.ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => (int)d.Value));` but that seems wrong.

Update:
For clarification,My result from the dapper sql query looks like this and I cannot change this.

```
IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>
```

**Desired Result:**

Using this result and LINQ, I need to end up with `Dictionary<int,List<int>>` where key is the GroupId, and List is a list of personsid in the group. But I can't quite figure out how to do it. So my end result dictionary will look like this

```
   Key    Value
    1       2,3
    2       4,6
```

Any help greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Your result is in the format of `List<IDictionary<string, object>>` but your data fits more the structure of `List<Tuple<x,y>>` - Can you please explain the extra level you have? How is it represented in the data that is returned?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question with my format

Comment: Thanks for updating. However I still don't understand how that fits with the data you describe that you got back form the procedure - at the beginning of the question..

Comment: why the heck do you await a **List<Dictionary<string, object>>**?? the result clearly shows that your return values is just a **Dictionary<TKey, TValue>**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `IDictionary<string, object>` is the Dapper way of representing (Name, Value) pairs (properties). In your case the keys should be "GroupId" and "PersonId", so you can achieve the goal with something like this:

```
var groupedResult = result.GroupBy(e => (int)e["GroupId"])
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(e => (int)e["PersonId"]).ToList());
```

Comment: @GiladGreen Haha, thanks! (as you know, I usually try to not guessing :)

Comment: Being good is to know and not guess, but when already guessing to guess good :)

Comment: Worked great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookup instead. So:

```
var lookup = result.ToLookup(r => r.GroupId, r => r.PersonId)
```

a lookup is conceptually the same as a dictionary, but allows for multiple values per key, so

```
lookup[1]
```

returns an `IEnumerable<int>` with values 2,3